# Change input type time to seconds in the controller

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

If you have an input type of time like below :

```
    <input type="time"
       ng-model="time">
```

and you pass the time through to your controller how do you go about converting that time entered to seconds ?

At that moment the scope time outputs the below :

> Thu Jan 01 1970 01:01:00 GMT+0000 (BST)

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your model value is a date you can get seconds like this :

```
scope.time.getTime()/1000
```

Comment: Legend this is what I needed thanks. Knew it would be simple